# Why is the address of a local variable identical for different executions?

Tags: c++

```
int fun(int x);

int main()
{
    fun(10);
    fun(11);   
    return 0;
}

int fun(int x)
{
    int loc;//local variable
    cout<<&loc;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
0xbfb8e610 
0xbfb8e610
```

Here loc is a local variable, which goes out of scope after the 1st execution of the function `f(10)`, then get allocated again for the next execution of `fun(11)`. So the address of `loc` variable has to  be different as per my understanding. Then why is the address `&loc` same for both the execution?

Comment: *"So the address have to be different."* What makes you think that?

Comment: Because they're called right after each other they get to use the same space on the stack.

Comment: @jrok>after loc variable goes out of scope after the 1st execution of fun() that memory will be resused by some other variable.Then how can both the execution of fun() yield the same address for loc.

Comment: Well, what other variable? :) There's nothing between the two calls to `fun`. If you take something off the stack and then put it back immediately, it'll be on the same place.

Comment: @SubiSuresh: Exactly as you said, it goes out of scope and is reused by some other variable -- in this case a different instance of `loc`.

Comment: @iWerner>This is just for my clarification.But it may not  be always the same right?

Comment: @SubiSuresh: You would expect it to be on typical implementations, but you can't rely on it. Both function calls occur under the same circumstances and are invocations of the same function, so you would expect the stack layout to be the same. But an implementation is free to do something bizarre if it wants to.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz>Now i understood,OS doesnt know both loc are the same.Its just another variable for OS. :-).This is what you meant right?.Thanks for the simple explanation

Comment: @SubiSuresh OS doesn't care. The compiler does, and the compiler sees two function calls after each other, so it uses the same piece of memory for both (implicitly; look up how the call stack works)

Comment: @jrok>I got it now ..By another variable,i meant same memory can be used by variable from some other process.Am i wrong about the statement i made?

Comment: @SubiSuresh No, they won't always be the same. David Schwartz' answer below explains why. 
Also, if you want to do something that relies on the values being the same you're implementing an anti-pattern. Don't do it.

Comment: @SubiSuresh The memory location is virtual. *'Do you think that's air you're breathing now?'*

Comment: @SubiSuresh: The same memory can't be used by another process because the OS won't let it. The same *address* can be used by another process, but it will access completely different memory. The operating system can create any number of distinct or partially overlapping memory spaces for processes to live in and can map bits and pieces of those spaces into pages of physical memory as needed. If you really want to take the red pill, read up on how `fork` is implemented using copy on write.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each invocation of `fun` needs its own place to store the variable. But as soon as the function returns, the variable no longer exists. There's no reason the address can't be re-used. It doesn't have to be, but there's no reason it can't be.

In a typical implementation, stack space is used to hold the information needed to return from a function and their local variables when a function is invoked. When the function returns, the local variables are removed from the stack and the return information popped off it, leaving the stack back where it was when the function was called. Since the two function invocations are the same, they wind up with the stack the same in both cases, making the local variable have the same address. This is what an experienced programmer would would expect, but not rely on.

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat ultra-simplistic (vague) illustration of what's happening on the stack.

`main()` (assuming `0xtopomain` remains constant):

```
   ~Stack~
==============
= 0xtopomain =
= 0x........ =
==============
```

First execution of `fun()` (push):

```
   ~Stack~
==============
= 0xothers.. =
= 0xbfb8e610 = <- loc
= 0xmemoffun = <- other memory allocated for fun()
= 0xtopomain =
= 0x........ =
==============
```

Back to `main()` (pop):

```
   ~Stack~
==============
= 0xtopomain = <- Where the hell is loc?!!
= 0x........ =
==============
```

Second execution of `fun()` (push again):

```
   ~Stack~
==============
= 0xothers.. =
= 0xbfb8e610 = <- loc's here again
= 0xmemoffun = <- other memory allocated for fun()
= 0xtopomain =
= 0x........ =
==============
```

Comment: >Thanks a lot for the picturisation

Answer (score 2):

Local variables stored in stack(a special memory area that new pushed variables stay at top, and old variables stay at the bottom). When you make a call for a function some operations done such as store return address, parameters and registers etc. But there is an order. And at the return time, all pushed variables popped from the stack. Since you are using the same function and between two call, you dont use any local variable in the main function, this is expected that your variable addresses are the same.